# Is there a simple Bash command which just sets the exit code?

Tags: bash

When testing exit code handling it is often useful to trigger an arbitrary exit code anywhere within the script, as a sort of hack approximating a Python `Mock` with `side_effect = Exception()`. For exit codes 0 and 1 there are the `true` and `false` builtins, but for any other exit code it seems there are only clunky options:

1. Using a subshell: `(exit "$exit_code")`. This is expensive and complex enough to possibly have unexpected side effects. Starting up a new shell probably invokes many thousands of lines of code, while a command specifically intended to set the exit code in line would probably be a handful of lines. Subshells are also a rare construct in production code, so a newbie could easily conclude that the code is equivalent to `exit "$exit_code"`.
2. Creating and invoking a custom function:

   ```
   simulate_exit_code() {
       return "$1"
   }
   simulate_exit_code "$exit_code"
   ```

   Cheap but additional complexity.

I'm asking whether there is a *better* option than either of the above, not which one of them is best (the first for brevity, the second for speed). Some dead simple builtin command like `set_exit_code "$exit_code"` would be ideal.

Comment: are you trapping anything? I find it hard to visualize when or why I would want such features in a bash program, but when I wanted to control exits, I used trap.

Comment: How are either of these complex? These are all entirely shell-internal

Comment: @muru `(exit "$exit_code")` is four or eight tokens, depending on how you count. The function solution is a lot more. Something like `false "$exit_code"` (analogous to `yes [some string]`, where the original command has been extended (or bastardised, depending on your take on "do one thing") to support a bunch of other use cases) is two or six tokens, depending on how you count. To a newbie the parentheses would just look like a useless grouping, and the subshell construct is not exactly googlable.

Comment: I'm not convinced. Why should there be a builtin for something which is *not* a common thing to do, when the required effect can be trivially obtained by simple existing shell constructs? (Seriously, who counts tokens?)

Comment: @muru I'm not saying this *should* exist. I'm asking whether it *does.*

Comment: And I'm saying it does - the two options you present *are* simple and are part of the shell.

Comment: Could you post that as an answer @muru?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One convoluted option would be:

```
. /dev/stdin <<< 'return "$exit_code"'
```

(doesn't fork, but creates a temp file or a pipe in 5.1+)

For completeness,

Note that in ksh93, `(exit "$ret")` doesn't fork a subshell, so is relatively efficient there.

`bash` is one of the rare few Bourne-like shells where you can't write it `set_status() return "$1"` for short.

In `zsh`, you could use an anonymous function:

```bsh
() return 3
```

When I have such a need, I personally use:

```
set_status() { return "$1"; }
```

Which seems the simplest to me.

But in conclusion, the answer to *is there a simple Bash command which just sets the exit code* is *no* AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a custom function is your best bet (option 2 in your question).

Comment: I'm explicitly looking for something *simpler* than the solutions I've outlined.

Comment: I understood that. I am simply stating that (to my knowledge at least) the simplest option available is a custom function.